# Python Simple Logic Program

Tags: python, logic

Question: POWERFUL ENOUGH

Your program will be given a number n as input. Print the first power of 2 that is larger than that number. For example, if num is 6 then you should print 8 because 2 cubed is 8 whereas 2 squared is only 4 and so not big enough.

Answer:

```
n = int(input())
i = 1
while n > 0:
  if 2**i > n:
      print(2**i)
      break
  i += 1
```

The above is the answer I came up with. I tried using for loop and many other variations but did not work.

This is a question from the Perse Coding Team Challenge [PCTC Sample R2 Q3]. I got 8/10 and the last test case says runtime error, It's a very straightforward code, I am not sure why it says runtime error.

Link of the website: https://pctc.cuttle.org/index.php?action=user_competitions

Comment: "Straightforward" is not necessarily the same as "fast enough".

Comment: @ScottHunter Can you please elaborate? I mean which way else would be the fastest?

Comment: Hint: the question mentions a number, not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at the problem statement and tried to solve it for myself. The reason why you get the runtime error is that the number `n` could be of type `float` (there is nothing said in the problem statement about the type of `n`). So, as I understand, in one test the float number is given to your program (for example `6.5`) and the `ValueError` appears because it cannot convert `6.5` to `int` type.

My solution gets 10/10 score. Here it is:

```py
n = float(input())
result = 1

while True:
  if result > n:
    print(result)
    break
  result *= 2
```

It is similar to yours except for a few things. No need to calculate the power of two on each loop cycle, you can just multiply the previous value by 2. Also I didn't use the `n > 0` condition because `n` could be a negative number too and in this case your program will not give any output!

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
next_power_of_2 = 2 ** (math.ceil(math.log2(n)))
print(next_power_of_2)
```

Try this solutions without loop :P